# How to output just columns of dataframe to file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data like this:

```
      aak  aamiiin  aamiin  aaran   ...    yusuf  zalecha  zaman  zootan
0       0        0       0      0   ...        0        0      0       0
1       0        0       0      0   ...        0        0      0       0
2       0        0       0      0   ...        0        0      0       0
3       0        0       0      0   ...        0        0      0       0
4       0        0       0      0   ...        0        0      0       0
```

and I want to output it into "data.txt" like so:

```
aak  aamiiin  aamiin  aaran   ...    yusuf  zalecha  zaman  zootan
```

Please help me..

Comment: `print(df.to_string(index=False))`?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([df.columns]).to_csv()` ?

Comment: `print(df.columns.to_series().tostring())` should work

Comment: just `df.columns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open a file like normal then extract the columns' values like so:

```
file = open("data.txt", "a") #"a" means append
file.write("\t".join(df.columns.values))
file.close()
```

Make sure to close the file when you are done!